# Enzyme returns null for stateful component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

So, hi guys.

I have a problem with enzyme I don't know why.

But I have this component:

```js
class Controller extends React.Component<ControllerProps & RouteProps, {}> {
    public state = {
        role: '',
    }

    public updateEmploeeList = (state): void => {
       console.log(state)
    }

[....]
}
```

and I am doing this test:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {shallow} from 'enzyme'
import Controller from '../../../src/Components/Controller/Controller'
import '../setupTests'
import {withRouter, RouteProps} from 'react-router-dom'

describe('Link', () => {
    it('Renders link to Google', () => {
        const controller = shallow<any>(<Controller hideFilter={false} RouteProps={RouteProps} />)
        const createInstance = controller.instance().updateEmploeeList('as')

        expect(createInstance).toBeCalledWith('as')
    })
})
```

But I'm receiving this message:

> ```
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateEmploeeList' of null
> ```

But it wasn't to be `null` because it's a stateful component.

Does someone know where is the error?

Comment: did you try using mount instead? as per the enzyme [docs](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/instance.html#react-16x), doing mount would give a correct instance.

Comment: You omitted a relevant piece of code. It's not evident that `Controller` component is `Controller` class. The problem suggests that it's not, otherwise you wouldn't have it. Considering that you use a router, it's likely a wrapper.